# Uploading images via the Magento SOAP API

Tags: c#, magento

I'm attempting to upload images to a Magento site using the SOAP API with C#.

This is what I have so far, but it isn't working, no exceptions are thrown or anything but when I go and look on the site the image is blank.

Do I need to do the Base64Encode? I only really tried this because [this](http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/01/30/magento-images-and-the-product_media-api/) PHP example does something similar. If I try it without I get a SOAP exception with the error message of "Bad Request".

```
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"c:\1.jpg");
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

    string fileConent = sr.ReadToEnd();

    byte[] encbuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileConent);
    string enc = Convert.ToBase64String(encbuff);

    var imageEntity = new catalogProductImageFileEntity();
    imageEntity.content = enc;
    imageEntity.mime = "image/jpeg";
    sr.Close();
    fs.Close();

    var entityP = new catalogProductAttributeMediaCreateEntity();
    entityP.file = imageEntity;
    entityP.types = new[] {"image", "small_image", "thumbnail"};
    entityP.position = "0";
    entityP.exclude = "0";

    _m.catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate(MageSessionProvider.GetSession(), SKU, entityP, "default");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This took me DAYS to work out.... this is how to do it

```
public void UploadProductImage(string SKU, string path)
        {
            var imageStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (var i = Image.FromFile(@"c:\ProductImages\" + path))   
            {
                       i.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
                byte[] encbuff = imageStream.ToArray(); 

            string enc = Convert.ToBase64String(encbuff,0 , encbuff.Length);


            var imageEntity = new catalogProductImageFileEntity();
            imageEntity.content = enc;
            imageEntity.mime = "image/jpeg";
            imageStream.Close();


            var entityP = new catalogProductAttributeMediaCreateEntity();
            entityP.file = imageEntity;
            entityP.types = new[] {"image", "small_image", "thumbnail"};
            entityP.position = "0";
            entityP.exclude = "0";

            _m.catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate(MageSessionProvider.GetSession(), SKU, entityP, "default");
            Console.WriteLine("Image Uploaded");
        }
```

Comment: +1 worked great. Just one question, when I have multiple images and I have a foreach loop wrapped around the whole code, it uploads the correct number if images but they are always only one image. Do I need to dispose the MemoryStream after each irritation of the loop? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've just started a project to integrate an existing system into Magento and the documentation is virtually non-existent.  This was EXACTLY what I needed.

Comment: If I could have given you +10^19 , I would.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Dan and I have been puzzled in the same issue on the same days,
and we get the same solution!

I'm using XML-RPC and the Magento API. I wrote this code as a part of a bigger class that read the image data from a file and makes it compatible with Magento API.

```
  internal void readFromFile(string fullImpgPath)
    {
        m_file.content = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullImpgPath));
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fullImpgPath).ToLower();
        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".gif":
                m_file.mime = "image/gif";
                break;

            case ".jpg":
            case ".jpeg":
                m_file.mime = "image/jpeg";
                break;

            case ".png":
                m_file.mime = "image/png";
                break;

            case ".bmp":
                m_file.mime = "image/bmp";
                break;

            case ".tif":
            case ".tiff":
                m_file.mime = "image/tiff";
                break;

            default:
                m_file.mime = "application/octet-stream";
                break;
        }
    }
```

The very important thing is that the "content" must be of type string and
must be obtained from bytes[] through the call of the system function `Convert.ToBase64String(...)`.

Concerning the [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type of the image, only "gif", "jpg" and "png" are supported
as I discovered looking inside the Magento API code.